# How do I pass parameters to a java servlet that is not directly entered by the user?

Tags: java, servlets

So in my website, I have the user submit the title and artist name of a song and I send that info to a servlet where I do some stuff with it and print the results to the screen.

Now, I want to create a feature where the user can then vote on how well the last process worked by using an input range. I know how to send this information to another servlet, but my question is: how would I send the original information (song name and artist) along with it? The only way I could think how is having the user re-enter it themselves but that is redundant.

Comment: See `<input type="hidden">` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto That works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Either of you should make an Answer of that comment’s solution, do as to accept it and thereby close this Question.